# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, I'm not experienced with JavaScript. Although I plan on sitting down and thoroughly learning the language, for now I'm just an HTML/CSS guy. I say this to avoid having my mind-blown by a response.

I'm having an issue with a site I've inherited. They've used what I believe is a script written by someone else for an image slider, and the page keeps coming back with the error I mentioned in the title. I'll post the code and hopefully someone can help me fix it (and teach me some things about JavaScript in the process).

**CODE:**  *The error Google Developer tools is sending back occurs on the very last line (JQuery)*

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $.fn.lofJSidernews = function( settings ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        // get instance of the lofSiderNew.
        new  $.lofSidernews( this, settings ); 
    });


 }

 $.lofSidernews = function( obj, settings ){
    this.settings = {

        mainItemSelector    : 'li',
        navInnerSelector    : 'ul',
        navSelector         : 'li' ,
        navigatorEvent      : 'click'/* click|mouseenter */,
        wapperSelector      : '.sliders-wrap-inner',

        interval            : 5000,

        startItem           : 0,
        navPosition         : 'vertical',/* values: horizontal|vertical*/ 

        duration            : 1200,
        navItemsSelector    : '.navigator-wrap-inner li',
        navOuterSelector    : '.navigator-wrapper' ,
        isPreloaded         : true,

        onPlaySlider:function(obj, slider){},
        onComplete:function(slider, index){  }
    }   
    $.extend( this.settings, settings ||{} );   
    this.nextNo         = null;
    this.previousNo     = null;
    this.maxWidth  = this.settings.mainWidth || 684;



    this.wrapper = $( obj ).find( this.settings.wapperSelector );   
    var wrapOuter = $('<div class="sliders-wrapper"></div>').width( this.maxWidth );
    this.wrapper.wrap( wrapOuter );



    this.slides = this.wrapper.find( this.settings.mainItemSelector ); 
    if( !this.wrapper.length || !this.slides.length ) return ;
    // set width of wapper
    if( this.settings.maxItemDisplay > this.slides.length ){
        this.settings.maxItemDisplay = this.slides.length;  
    }
    this.currentNo      = isNaN(this.settings.startItem)||this.settings.startItem > this.slides.length?0:this.settings.startItem;
    this.navigatorOuter = $( obj ).find( this.settings.navOuterSelector );  
    this.navigatorItems = $( obj ).find( this.settings.navItemsSelector ) ;
    this.navigatorInner = this.navigatorOuter.find( this.settings.navInnerSelector );
    // if use automactic calculate width of navigator

    if( this.settings.navigatorHeight == null || this.settings.navigatorWidth == null ){
        this.settings.navigatorHeight = this.navigatorItems.eq(0).outerWidth(true);
        this.settings.navigatorWidth = this.navigatorItems.eq(0).outerHeight(true);

    }
    if( this.settings.navPosition == 'horizontal' ){ 
        this.navigatorInner.width( this.slides.length * this.settings.navigatorWidth );
        this.navigatorOuter.width( this.settings.maxItemDisplay * this.settings.navigatorWidth );
        this.navigatorOuter.height( this.settings.navigatorHeight );

    } else {
        this.navigatorInner.height( this.slides.length * this.settings.navigatorHeight );   

        this.navigatorOuter.height( this.settings.maxItemDisplay * this.settings.navigatorHeight );
        this.navigatorOuter.width(  this.settings.navigatorWidth );
    }       
    this.slides.width( this.settings.mainWidth );   
    this.navigratorStep = this.__getPositionMode( this.settings.navPosition );       
    this.directionMode = this.__getDirectionMode();  


    if( this.settings.direction == 'opacity') {
        this.wrapper.addClass( 'lof-opacity' );
        $(this.slides).css({'opacity':0,'z-index':1}).eq(this.currentNo).css({'opacity':1,'z-index':3});
    } else { 
        this.wrapper.css({'left':'-'+this.currentNo*this.maxSize+'px', 'width':( this.maxWidth ) * this.slides.length } );
    }


    if( this.settings.isPreloaded ) {
        this.preLoadImage( this.onComplete );
    } else {
        this.onComplete();
    }

    $buttonControl = $( ".button-control", obj);
    if( this.settings.auto ){
        $buttonControl.addClass("action-stop");
    } else {
        $buttonControl.addClass("action-start");
    }
    var self = this;

    $( obj ).hover(function(){
            self.stop();    
            $buttonControl.addClass("action-start").removeClass("action-stop").addClass("hover-stop");
    }, function(){
        if( $buttonControl.hasClass("hover-stop") ){

            if( self.settings.auto ){
                $buttonControl.removeClass("action-start").removeClass("hover-stop").addClass("action-stop");
                self.play( self.settings.interval,'next', true );       
            }
        }
    } );


    $buttonControl.click( function() {
        if( $buttonControl.hasClass("action-start") ){
            self.settings.auto =true;
            self.play( self.settings.interval,'next', true );
            $buttonControl.removeClass("action-start").addClass("action-stop");
        } else{
            self.settings.auto =false;
            self.stop();    
            $buttonControl.addClass("action-start").removeClass("action-stop");
        }
    } );
 }
 $.lofSidernews.fn =  $.lofSidernews.prototype;
 $.lofSidernews.fn.extend =  $.lofSidernews.extend = $.extend;

 $.lofSidernews.fn.extend({

    startUp:function( obj, wrapper ) {
        seft = this;

        this.navigatorItems.each( function(index, item ){
            $(item).bind( seft.settings.navigatorEvent,( function(){
                seft.jumping( index, true );
                seft.setNavActive( index, item );                   
            } ));
            $(item).css( {'height': seft.settings.navigatorHeight, 'width':  seft.settings.navigatorWidth} );
        })
        this.registerWheelHandler( this.navigatorOuter, this );
        this.setNavActive( this.currentNo );
        this.settings.onComplete( this.slides.eq(this.currentNo ),this.currentNo  );
        if( this.settings.buttons && typeof (this.settings.buttons) == "object" ){
            this.registerButtonsControl( 'click', this.settings.buttons, this );

        }
        if( this.settings.auto ) 
        this.play( this.settings.interval,'next', true );

        return this;
    },
    onComplete:function(){
        setTimeout( function(){ $('.preload').fadeOut( 900, function(){  $('.preload').remove(); } ); }, 400 ); this.startUp( );
    },
    preLoadImage:function(  callback ){
        var self = this;
        var images = this.wrapper.find( 'img' );

        var count = 0;
        images.each( function(index,image){ 
            if( !image.complete ){                
                image.onload =function(){
                    count++;
                    if( count >= images.length ){
                        self.onComplete();
                    }
                }
                image.onerror =function(){ 
                    count++;
                    if( count >= images.length ){
                        self.onComplete();
                    }   
                }
            }else {
                count++;
                if( count >= images.length ){
                    self.onComplete();
                }   
            }
        } );
    },
    navivationAnimate:function( currentIndex ) { 
        if (currentIndex <= this.settings.startItem 
            || currentIndex - this.settings.startItem >= this.settings.maxItemDisplay-1) {
                this.settings.startItem = currentIndex - this.settings.maxItemDisplay+2;
                if (this.settings.startItem < 0) this.settings.startItem = 0;
                if (this.settings.startItem >this.slides.length-this.settings.maxItemDisplay) {
                    this.settings.startItem = this.slides.length-this.settings.maxItemDisplay;
                }
        }       

        this.navigatorInner.stop().animate( eval('({'+this.navigratorStep[0]+':-'+this.settings.startItem*this.navigratorStep[1]+'})'), 
                                            {duration:500, easing:'easeInOutQuad'} );   
    },
    setNavActive:function( index, item ){
        if( (this.navigatorItems) ){ 
            this.navigatorItems.removeClass( 'active' );
            $(this.navigatorItems.get(index)).addClass( 'active' ); 
            this.navivationAnimate( this.currentNo );   
        }
    },
    __getPositionMode:function( position ){
        if( position  == 'horizontal' ){
            return ['left', this.settings.navigatorWidth];
        }
        return ['top', this.settings.navigatorHeight];
    },
    __getDirectionMode:function(){
        switch( this.settings.direction ){
            case 'opacity': this.maxSize=0; return ['opacity','opacity'];
            default: this.maxSize=this.maxWidth; return ['left','width'];
        }
    },
    registerWheelHandler:function( element, obj ){ 
         element.bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta ) {
            var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
                vel = Math.abs(delta);
            if( delta > 0 ){
                obj.previous( true );
            } else {
                obj.next( true );
            }
            return false;
        });
    },
    registerButtonsControl:function( eventHandler, objects, self ){ 
        for( var action in objects ){ 
            switch (action.toString() ){
                case 'next':
                    objects[action].click( function() { self.next( true) } );
                    break;
                case 'previous':
                    objects[action].click( function() { self.previous( true) } );
                    break;
            }
        }
        return this;    
    },
    onProcessing:function( manual, start, end ){            
        this.previousNo = this.currentNo + (this.currentNo>0 ? -1 : this.slides.length-1);
        this.nextNo     = this.currentNo + (this.currentNo < this.slides.length-1 ? 1 : 1- this.slides.length);             
        return this;
    },
    finishFx:function( manual ){
        if( manual ) this.stop();
        if( manual && this.settings.auto ){ 
            this.play( this.settings.interval,'next', true );
        }       
        this.setNavActive( this.currentNo );
        this.settings.onPlaySlider( this, $(this.slides).eq(this.currentNo) );
    },
    getObjectDirection:function( start, end ){
        return eval("({'"+this.directionMode[0]+"':-"+(this.currentNo*start)+"})"); 
    },
    fxStart:function( index, obj, currentObj ){
            var s = this;
            if( this.settings.direction == 'opacity' ) { 

                $(this.slides).stop().animate({opacity:0}, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing,complete:function(){ 
                                                                                s.slides.css("z-index","1")
                                                                                s.slides.eq(index).css("z-index","3");                                                          
                                                                                    }} );
                $(this.slides).eq(index).stop().animate( {opacity:1}, { duration : this.settings.duration, 
                                                                        easing   :this.settings.easing,
                                                                        complete :function(){ s.settings.onComplete($(s.slides).eq(index),index); }} );
            }else {
                this.wrapper.stop().animate( obj, {duration: this.settings.duration, easing:this.settings.easing,complete:function(){ 
                                                                                                    s.settings.onComplete($(s.slides).eq(index),index)                                 
                                                                                                } } );
            }
        return this;
    },
    jumping:function( no, manual ){
        this.stop(); 
        if( this.currentNo == no ) return;      
         var obj = eval("({'"+this.directionMode[0]+"':-"+(this.maxSize*no)+"})");
        this.onProcessing( null, manual, 0, this.maxSize )
            .fxStart( no, obj, this )
            .finishFx( manual );    
            this.currentNo  = no;
    },
    next:function( manual , item){

        this.currentNo += (this.currentNo < this.slides.length-1) ? 1 : (1 - this.slides.length);   
        this.onProcessing( item, manual, 0, this.maxSize )
            .fxStart( this.currentNo, this.getObjectDirection(this.maxSize ), this )
            .finishFx( manual );
    },
    previous:function( manual, item ){
        this.currentNo += this.currentNo > 0 ? -1 : this.slides.length - 1;
        this.onProcessing( item, manual )
            .fxStart( this.currentNo, this.getObjectDirection(this.maxSize ), this )
            .finishFx( manual   );          
    },
    play:function( delay, direction, wait ){    
        this.stop(); 
        if(!wait){ this[direction](false); }
        var self  = this;
        this.isRun = setTimeout(function() { self[direction](true); }, delay);
    },
    stop:function(){ 
        if (this.isRun == null) return;
        clearTimeout(this.isRun);
        this.isRun = null; 
    }
})
})(jQuery)
```

It is on the last line that I receive *Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function*

Any ideas?

Comment: `$(...).ready()` does not return a function, it returns a jQuery object. You can't "call" a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
```

Not returning function so you should remove

```
})(jQuery)
```

And replace to

```
});
```

Also there is no need to pass `$` to ready handler and you can simplify it from:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
```

To

```
$( function() {
```

Comment: I've made those changes, however now the slider is not loading in my page?

Comment: It was loaded before? Can you show updated code or jsFiddle or example?

Comment: Yes it was loaded before. I simply changed the things you suggested, which DID rid me of the error in Google Developer tools, however the slider would not load.

The updated code would  the exact code I posted, but with the changes you suggested.

Comment: I left the ready function and simply used }); to replace })(jquery)

No errors in the console... but no slider either.

Comment: Do you have some live example? If no errors than problem in other place

Comment: Here isa JSFiddle of the entire script http://jsfiddle.net/xebqbjx1/

I should mention that in Internet Explorer I get the following errors:
Line: 13
Error: 'jQuery' is undefined ------ Line: 289
Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: @user3737700 it was in few places, try this code now http://jsfiddle.net/xebqbjx1/1/

Comment: Nope, still isn't working. I get the following errors: Line: 1
Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object ----------Line: 289
Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: It's hard to say then, we need live example where we can play

Comment: How would I go about that? I'm not able to play with the website as it is a business site that is currently operational. I'm making changes via localhost

Comment: Your code is too big. It's hard to say without example or HTML layout, etc. You need to locate some piece of code where the problem is